# ./src/components/CustomNavbar.jsx Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom ' in '/Users/Documents/GitHub/myweb_app/src/components'

Tags: reactjs, import, hyperlink, routes, router

Keep getting this error not sure what I am doing wrong

Failed to compile
./src/components/CustomNavbar.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-router-dom ' in '/Users/mikemutabazi/Documents/GitHub/myweb_app/src/components'

**code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {BrowserRouter as Router , Route} from 'react-router-dom' ; 

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom ';

import {Navbar,Nav,NavItem} from 'react-bootstrap';
 


export default class CustomNavbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <Navbar default collapseOnSelect>
                <Navbar.Header>
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                    <Link to ='/Home'>codeLife
                    </Link>
                    </Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle/>
                </Navbar.Header>
                <Navbar.Collapse>
                    <Nav pullRight>
                        <NavItem eventKey = {1} ComponentClass={Link} to ="/" >
                            Home
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey = {2} ComponentClass={Link} to ="/about" >
                            About
                        </NavItem>
                        <NavItem eventKey = {3} ComponentClass={Link} to ="/news" >
                            News
                        </NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                </Navbar.Collapse>
           </Navbar>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the package?

Comment: I installed the package already